# ajax запрос не работает

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

```js
$("#carname").on('change',function(){
    var car = $('#carname').val().trim(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'controller/car_search.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : "json",
        data:{
            car: car
        },
        success: function(response){
            $('#cont').html(response); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Произошла ошибка");
        }
    });             
});
```

```html
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="carname" id="carname" placeholder="Поиск автомобиля">
                    </form>
                    <div id="cont"></div>
```

И сам скрипт на php:

```
<?php 

include_once('db.php');

$car = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'car', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (isset($car))
{
    $query = ('SELECT * FROM carsekb WHERE car_name LIKE :car ORDER BY car_name ASC');
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(['car' => '%'.$car."%"]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $table = "<table>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
            $table .= "<tr>";
                $table .= "<td> {$results[$i]['car_name']} </td>";
                $table .= "<td> {$results[$i]['uberstart']} </td>";
                $table .= "<td> {$results[$i]['uberx']} </td>";
            $table .= "</tr>";
    } 
    $table .= "</table>"; 
    json_encode($table);
}
else
{
    json_encode("Вы прислали пустую переменную 'param_1'");
}

?>
```

Как я понял ajax получается success и далее не пойму что происходит вообще =( страница просто перезагружается, в адресной строке появляется соответствующий гет запрос, то есть его можно использовать, но как это все сделать без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: В приведенном примере нет ничего чтобы указывало на перезагрузку страницы при вводе данных в поле. Может у Вас ошибка в другом месте?

Comment: нее там остальное просто текст. Перезагрузка происходит когда я вбиваю данные в поле и жму enter. и проблема не только в перезагрузке: код не выполняет свою функцию: он должен выводить полученные данные вбитые в поиск, а не выводит ничего

Comment: Ну так верно все. У Вас же четко написано: `on change`. Т.е. ajax должен отрабатывать при изменении чего-либо в input, а не при подтверждении оного.

Comment: Дак он ни так ни так не работает

Comment: попробуйте добавить к `input` действие `onkeyup="myFunc(this.value)"`
А сама по себе функция пусть содержит ajax